# Error in VS2015 installation and Xamarin UWP not working

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, uwp, failed-installation

I'm trying to install VS2015 Community in my PC.
When I install everything at the end the installer gives to me the following message:

[image: Windows 10 SDK(10.0.10240) The installer failed. Fatal error during installation. Error code: -2147023293]

I've tried to install, reinstall, update but anything changed. The only consequence that I can see is that when I create a new Xamarin solution, when I run the UWP project using Local Machine as target it starts, but then I obtain this exception message.

[image: exception]

If I run the application from the Mobile emulator, it starts without problems.

Somewhere (sorry, I forgot the source) I've read that I should be sure to add following references for the project:

- Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP
- Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP

But I've only the first one, not the second. Maybe it's related to the installation issue?

I'm new to Xamarin and UWP, but UWP should be run to both Mobile devices and desktops, so why I have this behaviour? and what I can try to solve the installation problem that's probably related to this?

So, at the end, what I can try in order to fix the installation and allows the xamarin UWP project to run correctly in the local machine?

Comment: I think you should VS installation, not Xamarin. If VS installs correcly Xamarin should be ok. Is your PC Windows 10? may be that will help https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: I've already tried it. It says me that the SDK is already installed. If I uninstall it and then install this one nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

> If I run the application from the Mobile emulator, it starts without problems.

According to your error message, it seems you are using [**StatusBar**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn633864) in your project.

While using **StatusBar**, please note that this is not a Universal API, this class can be only used in Mobile Device. Because status bar only exists in Mobile devices, there is no such thing in desktop, table or IoT devices. So if you use this class on Local Machine, you will get an error, but in Mobile Emulator, it can work without problems.

For more info, please see **Requirements** section of [**StatusBar**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn633864).

Usually, when using `StatusBar`, we would use it with Runtime API check like following:

```
Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar statusBar = null;
if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar"))
{
    statusBar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
}

if (statusBar != null)
{
    //TODO
}
```

On Local Machine, as there is no `StatusBar`, `ApiInformation.IsTypePresent` method will return `false`. This will help us avoid the error. For more info, please see [Write adaptive code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/version-adaptive-code#write-adaptive-code).

> But I've only the first one, not the second. Maybe it's related to the installation issue?

I'm not sure why you can't find the **Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP**. But if you have used `StatusBar` and can build and run your project in Mobile Emulator, then you must have referenced **Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP**. Without this extension, we can't use `StatusBar` and the build will fail.

Depending on the SDK you've installed, you can find following extensions in **Reference Manager** (Right click **"References"** in your project and then select **"Add Reference"** → **"Universal Windows"** → **"Extensions"**).
[image]

I'd suggest you create a new **Blank App (Universal Windows)** project with Visual Studio to see if you have both the Desktop Extensions and Mobile Extensions. If you still have problem in new Blank App, I'd suggest you use [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller) to uninstall Visual Studio completely and also check the Control Panel to make sure you have uninstall all related stuffs like the SDKs. Then you can try to reinstall Visual Studio to see if it works.

Comment: In this case in order to build a Xamarin project that works also in desktop I need to create another UWP project in it and manage the missing status bar (and other stuff I suppose) correct? In addition, I've also used the Visual Studio Uninstaller in order to remove VS but after using it I've the same errors during installation. And even in this case I've thee Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP but not the Mobile one...

Comment: @Jepessen Have you tried with a new Blank App (Universal Windows) project? Does it have the same problem? Besides what's the Xamarin project you are using? If you have had a UWP project in the Xamarin project, there is no need to add another one. Using the [Map sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/CustomRenderers/Map/) for example, it only contains one UWP project and it can run on both Desktop and Mobile devices.

Comment: With a normal UWP app I've no problem, it runs. The problem is that when I create a new blank xamarin app (shared), and then try to run the UWP project (no code changes)...

Comment: @Jepessen: So in a normal UWP app, you can find both the Desktop Extensions and Mobile Extensions? I'm not sure what do you mean the Xamarin UWP project can't run on local machine. If you use `StatusBar` directly on Local Machine, it should not work. Maybe you can share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue so that we can know whether the problem is related to the installation issue or not.

Comment: I can find desktop extensions, but not mobile ones.

Comment: @Jepessen [This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bfc4c36d-88d3-4b65-9208-580ee1c1d19d/windows-10-sdk-10010240-the-installer-failed-fatal-error-during-installation-error-code?forum=vssetup) might be helpful. If it still doesn't work, I'm afraid you may think of reimaging the machine.